# How do I "translate" characters typed via JQuery?

Tags: jquery

I need to somehow change the character typed into a different utf8 character and was wondering how it can be achieved with jquery? Basically when some inputs are focused, I want to have English letters typed translated into other predefined character. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll probably need to use a [keypress](http://api.jquery.com/keypress/) handler.  You get the character code from the `which` field of the event.  You can then map this to the desired character.  You could store the mappings in an object:

```
var mapping = {
  "65": "é",
  "66": "á"
};
```

Then, do something like:

```
var targetChar = mapping[event.which];
```